# Conditional "depends_on" in compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a compose file where I have a `php` and `db` service. In the development environment the application is dependent on the local `db` service, but in production there's already a (non-dockerized) database running. I gave the `db` service a profile called "development", but now when I run it in production with `docker compose up` without the profile, I get the following:

> service db is required by php but is disabled. Can be enabled by profiles [development]

Is there a way to have this `depends_on` option only applicable based on a condition? For example if `APP_ENV=development`, or something like that? And if not, what would be the most elegant alternative?

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  php:
    context: "./docker/php"
    target: "${APP_ENV:?}"
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: "service_started"
  db:
    build:
      context: "./docker/db"
      profiles:
        - development
```

Comment: "*Is there a way to have this depends_on option only applicable based on a condition?*" - No --- "*And if not, what would be the most elegant alternative?*" - Have one compose-file for production and one for development.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have [multiple Compose files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/multiple-compose-files/).  These files are [merged](https://docs.docker.com/compose/multiple-compose-files/merge/) together, and override files can have extra settings or entire extra containers.

In the setup you describe, your base Compose file would have the main application, but not the database

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'
services:
  php:
    image: registry.example.com/php:${PHP_TAG:-latest}
```

You could augment this with settings for production only

```yaml
# docker-compose.prod.yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  php:
    environment:
      PGHOST: database.example.com
```

or have a separate Compose file with developer-oriented settings.  These would include the instructions on how to build the image, and in your setup it would also include the dedicated database container.

```yaml
# docker-compose.dev.yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  php:
    build: ./docker/php
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_started
    environment:
      PGHOST: db
  db:
    build: ./docker/db
```

Probably the easiest way to use these is to use a symbolic link to make one of the files named `docker-compose.override.yaml`

```bash
ln -s docker-compose.dev.yaml docker-compose.override.yaml
```

but you can also use a `docker-compose -f` option; note that you need to list *every* Compose file if you do, and you need to include it on *every* Compose invocation.

```yaml
docker-compose \
  -f docker-compose.yaml \
  -f docker-compose.dev.yaml \
  up -d
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to write startup sh script.
In the code I provide bellow I assumed the database you use is Postgres

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$APP_ENV" = "development" ]; then
    # Start the DB container
    docker-compose up -d db

    # Wait until the DB container is up and running
    until docker-compose exec db pg_isready -h localhost -U postgres > /dev/null 2>&1; do
        sleep 1
    done
fi

# Start the PHP container
docker-compose up -d php
```